# send email button not working, either opens desired url or sends email, not both simultaneously

Tags: php, html, forms, email

i'm stuck in between the two desired functions which I can't manage to occur simultaneously; I have an email submission form and I need it to redirect the user to a thank you page after hitting the "Submit" button. I'm providing you with 3 html alternatives and 1 php file.

When the html is like this, the email gets sent but the redirection doesn't work.

```
            <form id="contact_form" action="mailer.php" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
                                    <div class="message" style="display:none"><div id="contact_alert" class="alert"></div></div>
                <label for="name">Name:</label>
                <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="full-width help" title="Insert your name" />
                <label for="email">Email:</label>
                <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="full-width help" title="Insert your email" />
                <label for="message">Message:</label>
                <textarea name="message" id="message" cols="30" rows="7" class="full-width help" title="Insert your message"></textarea>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="button" />
            </form>
```

When i change the last line to this, it sends the email again but redirection still doesn't work:

```
            <form id="contact_form" action="mailer.php" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
                                    <div class="message" style="display:none"><div id="contact_alert" class="alert"></div></div>
                <label for="name">Name:</label>
                <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="full-width help" title="Insert your name" />
                <label for="email">Email:</label>
                <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="full-width help" title="Insert your email" />
                <label for="message">Message:</label>
                <textarea name="message" id="message" cols="30" rows="7" class="full-width help" title="Insert your message"></textarea>
                <a href="thank-you"><input type="submit" value="Submit" class="button" /></a>
            </form>
```

And finally when I change the last line to this, the redirection works but no email gets sent.

```
            <form id="contact_form" action="mailer.php" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
                                    <div class="message" style="display:none"><div id="contact_alert" class="alert"></div></div>
                <label for="name">Name:</label>
                <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="full-width help" title="Insert your name" />
                <label for="email">Email:</label>
                <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="full-width help" title="Insert your email" />
                <label for="message">Message:</label>
                <textarea name="message" id="message" cols="30" rows="7" class="full-width help" title="Insert your message"></textarea>
                <a href="thank-you"><input type="button" value="Submit" class="button" /></a>
            </form>
```

This is the php file:

```
<?php
$to = "info@domain.com";
$subject = "Hi Nick, this is ".$_POST['name'];
$name_field = $_POST['name'];
$email_field = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

$headers = 'From: '.$_POST['email'].'' . "\r\n" .
'Reply-To: '.$_POST['email'].'' . "\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

$body = $message;

mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers );
header('Location: http://www.domain.com/thank-you') ;
?>
```

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I really don't know what you're trying to accomplish by wrapping that `<a></a>` around your button, but that is not a thing that you can do in HTML and expect something sane to happen. The first iteration of your form should work fine. Tell us the specific way in which it "doesn't work". Include error messages, because I'm guessing there are some.

Comment: @remy is that the end of the PHP script? The PHP docs seem to recommend that you `exit;` after calling `header()` to ensure that no further script is executed.

Comment: @Sammitch wrapping the <a></a> around my button opens the thank-you page but only when input type="button". so in the 1st iteration the email gets sent but no redirection takes place.  no error messages appear on my screen, just nothing seems to happen besides me receiving the email.

Comment: @DavidJohnSmith yes, this is the end of my script. it's just a php files with those lines that i call with the send button but the redirection doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

In the third html block, the redirection works because it is a simple hyperlink because `<input type=button>` defines a clickable button (mostly used with a JavaScript to activate a script).
Therefore no form will be submitted but the hyperlink will work.

In the second html block, the hyperlink wont work because `<input type=submit>` will make it a submit button with a default behavior of submitting the form to the action file and so the hyperlink won't work.

I know this doesn't answer the question but just felt like telling you the reasons.

Answer (score 0):

> ## ✓ EDIT (actual code used for successful submission)

---

### HTML form

```
<form id="contact_form" action="mailer.php" method="post">
<div class="message" style="display:none"><div id="contact_alert" class="alert"></div></div>
    <label for="name">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="full-width help" title="Insert your name" />
    <label for="email">Email:</label>
    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="full-width help" title="Insert your email" />
    <label for="message">Message:</label>
    <textarea name="message" id="message" cols="30" rows="7" class="full-width help" title="Insert your message"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="button" />
</form>
```

### Mail handler

```
<?php

$to = "email@example.com";

$subject = "Hi Nick, this is ".$_POST['name'];
$name_field = $_POST['name'];
$email_field = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

$headers = 'From: '.$_POST['email'].'' . "\r\n" .
'Reply-To: '.$_POST['email'].'' . "\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

$body = $message;

mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers );
header('Location: http://www.example.com/thank-you');

// commented out for testing purposes.
// Email was sent and received successfully
// echo "Success";
?>
```

---

---

> ## ✓ Original answer (Aug. 14, 2013)

---

**This** => `enctype="text/plain"` should not be used inside `<form>` elements, and that is why you were having problems.

### Try it with this reformatted form:

```
<form id="contact_form" action="mailer.php" method="post">
<div class="message" style="display:none"><div id="contact_alert" class="alert"></div></div>
    <label for="name">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="full-width help" title="Insert your name" />
    <label for="email">Email:</label>
    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="full-width help" title="Insert your email" />
    <label for="message">Message:</label>
    <textarea name="message" id="message" cols="30" rows="7" class="full-width help" title="Insert your message"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="button" />
</form>
```

---

---

I replaced this:

```
<form id="contact_form" action="mailer.php" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
                                                        /--------------------/
```

with this:

```
<form id="contact_form" action="mailer.php" method="post">
```

And this is **invalid:**

```
<a href="thank-you"><input type="button" value="Submit" class="button" /></a>
```

This is **valid:**

```
<a href="thank-you.html">Click here</a>
```

As is this is also valid:

```
<input type="button" value="Submit" class="button" />
```

Comment: i removed the enctype="text/plain" and everything happens the same way, so no difference there. the 2nd valid argument of yours, i tried it a lot of times with and without the <a href></a> tags but it doesn't work. with those tags it opens the redirection page but with no email and without them nothing happens, no redirection and no email gets sent. the 1st valid line of yours just creates a link that takes you to the desired page, it doesn't help with the email form though.

Comment: @remy That's impossible, I **"tested"** my code and I can assure you that it works. Otherwise I would not have posted this answer. Are you sure you used the form that's in my answer, and not some other from your example code?

Comment: could you paste here your code exactly as it is in your html file and also the php code? do you also call an external php file that does the redirection for you?

Comment: @remy Your redirection happens when the email has been sent, with your `header('Location: http://www.domain.com/thank-you');`. Doing a link won't work inside your form, i.e. `<a href="thank-you"><input type="submit"...` as I said, I tested my answer before posting. If you tried something else and did not mention it in your question, then I don't know what's wrong on your end.

Comment: @remy You'll have to give me a few minutes, I have to find it in my files. If not, I'll just retest and post everything.

Comment: thank you Fred, I appreciate it. But somehow i feel that the problem lies within the php file. Could it be server side? Something not enabled by the host?

Comment: @remy You're welcome. That could very well be that you're having server side problems. There could be many factors. Are you doing this on a local machine or on a paid/free hosted web service?

Comment: i copied both of your codes changing of course the appropriate fields to reflect my domain. now the email gets sent but the redirection is not happening.

Comment: @remy what is the code you're using to redirect and where are you putting it in?

Comment: it's this line inside the php file: header('Location: http://www.example.com/thank-you');

Comment: @remy If that is the exact syntax you used, it won't work. You need to use your own URL for it. For example, try `header('Location: http://www.google.com');` - it will only redirect `IF` the mail was successfully sent. Otherwise, if mail was not, then it won't work. Are you sure that you have the `mail()` function available?

Comment: yes I do, but it depends on how I syntax the html last line of the code. if i write this:     <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="button" /> the email will get sent but no redirection takes place and if I write this:                 <a href="thank-you"><input type="button" value="Submit" class="button" /></a> then the redirection happens but with no email whatsoever. I just can't have both at the same time!

Comment: @remy I need to see your entire code for both the HTML page/form and the PHP that you're using, this just doesn't make sense. I've never seen anything like that, acting so weirdly. I'm completely baffled.

Comment: thank you for your help Fred but i think i'm gonna use a plugin to work it out. it just doesn't wanna work. I haven't got the appropriate rep points to mark your answer as helpful but thank you! cheers